# The Roth IRA clock and taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira

Please consider the following hypothetical situation:

A 30 year old investor puts $500 into a Roth IRA. When he turns 36, he takes all the money  out and pays taxes on his profits and maybe a penalty too. Now, on his 60th birthday he decides to start saving for his future so he puts $500 into a Roth IRA. A month later, the  account has a value of $550 and he takes all out. Is the $50 he made, tax free?

I think it is because he has money in  a Roth  IRA  for 5 years and  he is over 59.5 years of age.

Comment: The issue  would be being able to prove the 5 year requirement was met. Does the IRS keep the first instance of having an Roth IRa in their database? And do you still have a statement decades later?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep You raise an important issue  about enforcement. However, for purposes of this question assume that all the facts given can be proved to the satisfaction  of the IRS.

Comment: Is there a reason the investor is shooting themselves in the foot by not putting money into the IRA until it's too late for that to help them much?

Comment: Would the financial institution really keep open an (any) account with no activity for 24 years? (yeah, I know, not the point of the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A in IRA stands for *A*rrangement, not *a*ccount. In the scenario you're describing, the tax payer satisfied the 5 year requirement since the distribution was more than 5 years later after the Roth IRA was *first* established to the taxpayer's benefit (which was at the age of 30).

See the [IRS Publication 590-B](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p590b#en_US_2022_publink100089543):

> A qualified distribution is any payment or distribution from your Roth IRA that meets the following requirements.
>
> - It is made after the 5-year period beginning with the first tax year for which a contribution was made to a Roth IRA set up for your benefit.
>
> ...